# general equation for a n-side regular polygon

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, polygons

I was revisiting some geometry problems, and i got me thinking if there is any king of general equation to describe a n-side polygon? Some way similar to the equation that describe a circle, which we can integrate, rescue pretty much any particular information of the circle from the equation.

Comment: regular or any irregular n-sided polygon? Which equation for a circle are you referring to make your analogy/connection, there are several out there?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon

Comment: in the regular n-sided polygon context i think the association would be similar to the conic section equation, something like : 0 = xˆ2 + yˆ2 + Ax + By + F.

Comment: @JeremiasJunior Yes, but can you find a solid that has all the regular polygons as cross-sections? To start, there are infinitely many types of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General equation for any given n-sided polygon:
[image]

Source: https://danpearcymaths.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/does-a-function-exist-to-describe-a-square-what-about-any-polygon/

Comment: Was exacly what i was searching for. Thanks :)

Comment: You're most welcome! :)